# How to use cbind() when columns stored in a character vector?

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have the below data.table:

```
DT <- data.table(x=rep(c(1,2),3),y=rep(1,6),z=rep(2,6))

DT
   x y z
1: 1 1 2
2: 2 1 2
3: 1 1 2
4: 2 1 2
5: 1 1 2
6: 2 1 2
```

and I am calculating the rowMeans across columns y,z. Can I use the cbind() if the column names are in a character vector?

```
colN = c('y','z')
```

I know that DT[, meanYZ := rowMeans(cbind(y,z))] works. But is there a way to make this work with colN? So, like --

```
DT[, meanYZ := rowMeans(cbind(colN)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred option would be through `.SDcols` to specify the columns of interest, apply the `rowmeans` on the `.SD` (Subset of Data.table)

```
library(data.table)
DT[, meanYZ := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = colN]
```

---

It can also be done with `mget` to return a `list`, `cbind` them with `do.call` and apply the `rowMeans`

```
DT[, meanYZ := rowMeans(do.call(cbind, mget(colN)), na.rm = TRUE)]
```

---

`cbind(y, z)` works as `y` and `z` are unquoted, while the elements in `colN` are strings `"y"` and `"z"`.  It needs to be either converted to `sym`bol or `name` (`as.name`) and `eval`uated or use `get` to return the values of the column when it searches on the environment of the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can subset the columns in `colN` from `DT` first and then generate a new column for `rowMeans`, e.g.,

```
DT[, MeanYZ := rowMeans(.SD[, colN, with = FALSE])]
```

or

such that

```
   x y z MeanYZ
1: 1 1 2    1.5
2: 2 1 2    1.5
3: 1 1 2    1.5
4: 2 1 2    1.5
5: 1 1 2    1.5
6: 2 1 2    1.5
```

Comment: @akrun WoW, that's cool! I learn a lot from you! Thank you!